# How to make a main window large enough to show the full title

Tags: java, string, swing

I mean the following:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hello swing");
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.add(new JButton("A"));
frame.add(panel);
frame.pack();
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

But this code displays this

[image: Short]

Is there a way to display something like this right after starting up?

[image: Long]

I mean so that the whole title can be seen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the length of the title and apply it to the new dimension used. However I haven't tested it, you have to play with the numbers yourself. Just giving you the idea.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hello swing");
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
int len = frame.getTitle().length();
Dimension dimension = new Dimension(200 + 7*len, 200);
panel.setPreferredSize(dimension);
```

I guess using the number `7` as the constant would be the best. However be aware of using wide (`wwww..`) or narrow letters `(iiii...)` mostly, because they appear in different widths. To get the exact length, you have to use method of such as  [`Graphics.getFontMetrics`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#getFontMetrics()) and [`FontMetrics.stringWidth`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html#stringWidth(java.lang.String)) are.

Take a look at the example acording my code on the top:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to avoid using setPrefferedSize? Becuase as far as I got it's not a very good thing...

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
```

to expand your frame

Comment: We should avoid using setXxxSize shouldn't we?

Comment: Not a very good answer to the question, which is if we can set the frame to always display the title. Of course we can set it to be huge, but that's a pretty awful way of doing things.